# Кастомные метки на Google maps считывая с <table hidden>

Tags: javascript, html5

Код просто хочет работать.
Нужно сделатьЖ
1. Должна быть картой Google построенной на Google Maps APi v3
2. Синим цветом имеют подсвечиваться указанные страны
3. Центр карты заполнена определяться автоматически
4. Данные для карты должны приниматься с скрытой таблицы

Сам код сдесь:
http://jsfiddle.net/op3x8n1j/

```
table hidden>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDAmDz0Mv9VcspygtA3rumHP4d2PR3H7wM"></script>
<thead>
    <th>County</th>
    <th>Lat</th>
    <th>Lon</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Wroclawskie</td>
        <td>51.0396704</td>
        <td>16.9454582</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>51.07675</td>
        <td>13.6325032</td>

    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>50.7969446</td>
        <td>2.6248715</td>

    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Britain</td>
        <td>52.6360565</td>
        <td>-1.2011397</td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

З.Ы.
не знаю работает ли правильно пункт 2
и не доконца могу понять как сделать пукт 3

код под UIKit

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/op3x8n1j/2/

случайно при копировании не исправил id для js.

Comment: переделал немного

http://jsfiddle.net/op3x8n1j/4/